# Postback Happening inside UpdatePanel when CheckBox is Checked

Tags: asp.net, ajax, listview, updatepanel, postback

I have a `ListView` and inside it I'm having a `CheckBox` for which `AutoPostBack` is set to `true`, I also have a Collapsible panel kept inside the same `ListView` adjacent to this `CheckBox`.

The entire thing is kept inside an `UpdatePanel` for Silent Post back. Now my problem is even though it is kept inside a `UpdatePanel` when I click on the `CheckBox` the Entire page is getting Refreshed. I need to do it using a Silent PostBack. How can i Achieve this??

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewGroups" runat="server" 
        onitemdatabound="ListView1_ItemDataBound">


    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table runat="server" style="">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    No data was returned.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td>
            <asp:Panel ID="PanelContainer" runat="server" Width="400px">

                <asp:Panel ID="PanelHeaderList" runat="server" Width="20px">
                <div style="float:left;" >
                <asp:ImageButton ID="Image1" runat="server" 
                                 ImageUrl="~/expand_blue.jpg" 
                                 AlternateText="(Show Details...)"/>
                </div>
                 </asp:Panel>
                <div style="float:left;" >       
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
                                  AutoPostBack="true" />            
                <asp:Label ID="Grp_NameLabel" runat="server" 
                           Text='<%# Eval("Grp_Name") %>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfGrpID" runat="server" 
                                 Value='<%#Eval("Grp_ID") %>' />
                </div>
              <br />
                <p>
                <asp:Panel ID="PanelGroupsItem" runat="server" 
                           Width="100px" >
                <asp:Panel ID="MyGroups" runat="server" 
                           ScrollBars="Vertical" 
                           Height="200px" 
                           Width="300px" 
                           Visible='<%# GetFlag(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Grp_ID"))) %>'>

                   //Another Normal gridView here just showing some data


                   </asp:Panel>
                </asp:Panel>

                <asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender1"
                                  runat="server"
                                  Collapsed="true"
                                  TargetControlID="PanelGroupsItem"
                                  CollapseControlID="PanelHeaderList"
                                  ExpandControlID="PanelHeaderList"
                                  ImageControlID="Image1"
                                  ExpandedImage="~/collapse_blue.jpg"
                                  CollapsedImage="~/expand_blue.jpg"
                                  SuppressPostBack="true"
                >
                </asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
                </asp:Panel>
                </p>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server">
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server">
                    <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" 
                           border="0" style="">
                        <tr runat="server" style="">
                            <th runat="server">
                                Groups</th>

                        </tr>
                        <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server" style="">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

Please help me on this

Comment: what are the attributes set on the updatepanel?

Comment: I tried with both Conditional and Always.. but its not working. i have not set any other attributes

Comment: You should include the markup of your `Updatepanel`, since it's probably something with it that causes the problem. Also, what you call "Silent Post back" is called an "AsyncPostBack".

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for a similar issue here: [Checkboxlist inside UpdatePanel triggers full postback when an item is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260567/checkboxlist-inside-updatepanel-triggers-full-postback-when-an-item-is-checked).

You need to set the ClientID mode of the checkBox to AutoID.